# Adjusting the p5.js colorpicker function

Tags: p5.js, color-picker

For a stimulus presentor I want to create a color picker using p5.js.
I found out there is already a wonderful colorpicker function that does almost exactly what I want ([p5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createColorPicker)). However, I would like it not to display the RGB numbers below the selector. And if possible I would also like to adjust the size of the selector. Does anybody know if it is possible to adjust these things? And if so how?

[image: Current appearance]

I tried looking in the p5.js reference, but it seems to me that there is no direct way of adjusting the colorselector in any way.